# Xcode cannot launch apps on the simulated device “iPhone 6 Plus”, as it is currently running app

Tags: objective-c, ios9, xcode7

I am facing this issue with Xcode 7 . I tried stopping project run, Cleaned and then Built but still the issue occurs...Please have a solution to this
[image]

Comment: Kill the simulator and restart Xcode.

Comment: Have you stopped the process of the Simulator? its independent of xCode

Comment: Thanks bro restarting my system worked !!!

Comment: Maybe you post the answer yourself and mark it as solved!

Comment: Just click "Reset content & setting..." of Simulator. Force quit you Xcode & simulator. Reopen your Xcode & perform deep clean by pressing"Shift+alt+command+K". Now everything will work fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem got solved by simply restarting the system once again.

Comment: Happens a lot. Most of these issues can be resolved by killing the simulator / Xcode / rebooting them system.